# Hosting multiple websites on apache2

Tags: apache, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I want to be able to access each site like this: `http://server_ip/project_name`.
I don't want different domains or different ports.

I have these files in the available sites folder.

test1.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test1/public_html
    ServerName test1
</VirtualHost>
```

test2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test2/public_html
    ServerName test2
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to `htttp://localhost/test1` I get **Not Found**.
But when I go to `localhost` I get test1 page.

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. You want to serve a different document root based on the fact you'd use either the IP or a hostname?

Comment: I want to see test1 page in: `http://localhost/test1` and test2 page in `http://localhost/test2`

Comment: Virtualhosts won’t solve that. As their name indicates, they are host based configurations. What you’re looking for is aliases, or just create 2 folders in your document root. It’s obviously local dev so security and rights shouldn’t be a concern